# VBA: Problem with passing arguments to userform

Tags: vba, properties, userform

I have searched and tried for 6 hours now but I can't solve the problem.

My idea:
I want to show a userform in Excel-VBA with some radiobuttons, one listelement and one textfield. 
I want to pass some arguments to the userform to work with it because I don't want to calculate inside the userform-code (which works)
I don't want to declare global variables as well.

I tried the following which worked:

- calculate directly in the userform
- global variables

This hasn't worked:

- declared userform as variable and worked with the variable
- every possible combination of `[Public|Private|Friend] Property Let (ByRef|ByVal)`
- `Property Set` doesn't work in any case

The code from my main (module)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With New usr_mainInput
        .counter = 3
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

My code in the userform

```vb
Option Explicit

Private miCounter As Integer

Property Get counter() As Integer
    counter = miCounter
End Property
Property Let counter(c As Integer)
    Set miCounter = c
End Property

Private Sub userform_initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To counter           'miCounter don't work as well
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub btn_ok_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Object variable or With block variable not set

If it comes to the `Property Let counter()` it drops a compile error:

> Object required (Error 424)

Comment: Get rid of `Set` in `Property Let counter()`.

Comment: I think i get it... the moment ```_initialize``` is to early, the ```.counter``` isn't set at this time and in the ```Property Let counter()``` I don't have to ```Set miCounter = c```, that's the cause of the dropped error.

With ```_activate``` it works. I'll try tomorow in the office with my live-program, this was just a short reconstruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Property Let counter(c As Integer)
>     Set miCounter = c
> End Property
> ```

An *object is required*, only because of the `Set` keyword. This isn't a reference assignment, it's a value assignment.

View it like this:

```
Property Let counter(c As Integer)
    Let miCounter = c
End Property
```

Just don't actually type up the `Let` keyword (it *would* work though), [it's obsolete](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ObsoleteLetStatement) :)

Also note that the implicit modifier for `Property Let/Set` procedure argument, is always `Byval` - this is different than anything else in VBA, where thr implicit modifier is `ByRef`; consider making the `ByVal` modifier explicit.

---

> ```
> Private Sub userform_initialize()
>     Dim i As Integer
>     For i = 1 To counter           'miCounter don't work as well
>         Debug.Print i
>     Next i
> End Sub
> ```

That loop will never iterate anything, because the `Initialize` handler runs here:

> ```
> With New usr_mainInput
> ```

I mean, it runs when the `New usr_mainInput` instruction returns, *but before the object reference is given to the `With` block* (note that this is true for any class, not just forms) - that's well before the `.counter = 3` assignment! Rule of thumb, you want to *initialize* instance state in that handler, not consume it.

Consider using the `Activate` handler instead. That one will run immediately after the `.Show` call.